# how to update multiple documents in mongodb using node Based on unique id

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

How can update multiple docs in mongoose, I aware of how to update multiple docs which matches with other docs, but I want update multiple docs to be updated using the id.

I tried many ways, Here is one of it.

> Updated

```
var myid = req.params.noteId

   Note.updateMany({ _id:{ $in:ObjectID(myid) } }, {

       lname: req.body.lname || "Untitled Note",
       age: req.body.age
   }, { new: true })
       .then(note => {
           if (!note) {
               return res.status(404).send({
                   message: "Note not found with id " + req.params.noteId
               });
           }
           res.send(note);
       })
```

And One more thing How can I pass multiple Ids as parameters to update multiple docs in a postman tester.

Comment: `mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid` will return boolean value. check this https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/f7efecc04240525931402116f881b5984af800c4/lib/bson/objectid.js#L247

Comment: And why are you using `$in` operator for a single id match? Probably what you are looking for is `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(myid)`

Comment: Not for single id, I am providing two Id's. I tried `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(myId)` also, getting `TypeError: mongoose.Types.ObjectID is not a function`  this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid` will return boolean value. check this https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/f7efecc04240525931402116f881b5984af800c4/lib/bson/objectid.js#L247

If you want update for multiple ids to pass those ids inside req.body

for multiple use $in else pass directly.

```
var myid = req.params.noteId;

if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(myid)) {
    Note.update({
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(myid)
           // _id: {$in: req.body.somekey_array.map(id => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id ))} //multiple
        }, {

            lname: req.body.lname || "Untitled Note",
            age: req.body.age
        }, {
            multi: true //multiple
        })
        .then(note => {
            console.log('----qqqqq--', note)
            if (!note) {
                return res.status(404).send({
                    message: "Note not found with id " + req.params.noteId
                });
            }
            res.json(note);
        });
} else {
    res.status(400).json({
        msg: 'id not correct'
    });
}
```

Comment: It is taking single Ids only, If I provide more than one Id it is executing else block

Comment: if you are passing using body then you have to update condition.

Comment: `localhost:3000/notes/5d68c4e15269f90c08a99e79,5d68c8c4b5d7031a68235a3f`  Can I pass like this. I am using postman

Comment: @manjesha does your express route defined like this `/notes/:noteId` And if its a `GET` u'll need to use `const idsArr = (req.params.noteId).split(",")` then use that `idsArr` to pass on to `$in` op. And do update the question with how are the routes defined.